# Why isn't כל הכשר להצניע…‏ in שלחן ערוך?

Tags: shabbat, maseches-shabbos, shulchan-aruch, hotzaa-carrying-reshuyot

The seventh chapter of *mishnayos Shabas* has this general rule ("כלל"):

> Whatever is fit for storing and people store that [amount of it], and he carried it out on *Shabas*, he's liable therefor to bring a *korban chatas*. Whatever is not fit for storing, or people don't store that [amount of it], and he carried it out on *Shabas*, he's not liable, except one who stores it.

The subsequent *mishnayos* — off and on for the next three chapters (!) — give specific examples of this: how much food is fit for storing, how much wine, how much rope, how much hide, how much ink, how much wood, and so on and so forth.

And this is all codified in the *Rambam* (*Shabas* chapter 18), as well as in the halachic restatements of the *Rif* and *Rosh* (ad loc.).

But it's not in the *Shulchan Aruch*. Or at least: There's no reference to *Shulchan Aruch* in the *En Mishpat – Ner Mitzva* for any of these *mishnayos*, and I can't find them in the *Shulchan Aruch* anywhere.

Why not?

---

I was thinking to answer as follows (but this answer doesn't work, as I'll show). It may be because *Shulchan Aruch* is not concerned with nowadays-impractical topics like *korbanos*. Whether a prohibition is *mid'oraysa* (divinely imposed) or *mid'rabanan* (rabbinically imposed) [is important even nowadays](/q/34431), but — I thought — carrying out even less than a worthwhile amount of a substance is forbidden *mid'oraysa* (because of the principle of "*chatzi shiur asur min hatora*", "a part-measure is forbidden *mid'oraysa*"), which renders these *mishnayos* relevant only to the issue of *korban* and thus moot nowadays. However, that's not the case: *Aruch Hashulchan* (301:34) clarifies that "a part-measure for all [labors](/tags/melacha-creative-work/info) **except carrying out** is forbidden *mid'oraysa*". So that proposed answer doesn't work.

Comment: Perhaps, in spite of the fact that there are *nafka minos* between biblical and Rabbinic law even nowadays, where the distinctions between them are less likely to be very practical, the Shulchan Aruch is not as inclusive. If memory serves, this is not the only instance of this type of omission in the Shulchan Aruch.

Comment: Does the end of the Tur here answer your question? https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%98%D7%95%D7%A8_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%97

Comment: @DoubleAA, I don't know whether by "_isura_" he means _mid'oraysa_, in which case his statement does (according to the _AHS_) not apply to the _halachos_ I'm asking about, or whether by "_isura_" he means even _mid'rabanan_, in which case his statement answers my question **if** it applies to the _halachos_ I'm asking about (and I have no reason to think it does/doesn't). Thanks for the link, though: I hadn't seen that.

Comment: Do these Halachot get codified in any later codes or quoted in any later responsa?

Comment: @IsaacMoses I haven't seen them in _MB_ 301 or, um, is it 303? the one that discusses _bame haisha yotz'a_. _AHS_ discusses them (as alluded to in the question). I haven't checked elsewhere. Why do you ask?